# How to see the result of macro processing of a .cpp file?

Tags: c++, visual-c++, macros, g++

I'm reading some c++ library code and there are lots of macros.

I'm wondering how can I substitute all the macros to final code of the whole .cpp file?

I'm using g++ and msvc, if it's compiler related, either should be fine.

Comment: Most compilers have options to run code through the preprocessor and stop there. Look at the documentation for your compiler.

Comment: which compiler are you using?

Comment: `g++` and `clang++` have `-E`.

Comment: For msvc it's `/E` IIRC, but `-E` should be fine as well.

Comment: Note: _"I'm wondering if there is a tool/method which can substitute all the macros to final code of the whole .cpp file?"_ Asking for tools or any other 3rd party resources is _off-topic_ here.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ if g++ is a tool, it happens that I ask about that tool.

Comment: @FelixFXu but it won't help you with the step of _"substitution"_. There's further processing needed of these sources generated.

Answer (score -1):

thanks for the comments above, `-E` is the correct answer and I extend it to be a full one here.

The answer is:

```
g++ -E ./global/tagging.cpp -B /mnt/d/Test
```

`-E` is to preprocess the file as suggested in the comment above.

Usually a .cpp file will include .h files and `-B` is to set where to find the include files (otherwise it's very likely that g++ can't find .h files)

`-o` is optional to set the output file but when it's not used, the output will be in the terminal where I run `g++`.

When the cpp file includes lots of header files (recursively) the output is very long and is like: (search the file name of "tagging.cpp")

```
# 95 "./global/tagging.cpp"
 extern __attribute__((alias("_" "ccc"))) const char ....;
```

which means `tagging.cpp` file's line number 95 is preprocess to be the code following.

Comment: Not so sure how this answers your question? Did you mean to edit your question to add additional information about your concrete problem?